# Camel MongoDB : how to add cutsom converters

Tags: apache-camel

I have looked at the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/mongodb.html#MongoDB-Typeconversions) but couldn't find how to add custom type converters for mongoDB. How can one do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I think that `fromAnyObjectToDBObject` default converter can resolve most of your cases. It uses **Jackson** library and all you need is to mark your custom classes with right annotations.

Anyway, if you still need custom converter, following steps should be performed:

1. White your conversion logic and mark your class and converter methods with `org.apache.camel.Converter` annotation:

   ```
   package com.acme.converters;

   @Converter
   public class CustomConverter {

     @Converter
     public static DBObject fromCustomToDBObject(CustomType object) {
       // conversion logic
     }

   }
   ```
2. Create following resource file to be placed in your result jar:

**META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter**

And list your converter classes in this file:

*com.acme.converters.CustomConverter*

This file will help **Camel** to auto-discover your own converters.

You can also take a look at:

- `META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/TypeConverter` in **camel-mongodb-x.x.x.jar** to see how default converter defined
- `org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader` class to check converters loading logic

Comment: BTW for the jackson annotations sometimes the classes are not yours (ex. joda-time, util.Currency ..etc) so you have to create your own converters :)